# taskdef Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties

Tags: eclipse

when i try to ant for eclipse, it shows below info:

```
ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~[04:06]$ cd floodlight/
ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/floodlight[04:07] (master)$ ant
Buildfile: /home/ubuntu/floodlight/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties. It could not be found.

init:

compile:

compile-test:

dist:
     [echo] Setting Floodlight version: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
     [echo] Setting Floodlight name: floodlight
      [jar] Building jar: /home/ubuntu/floodlight/target/floodlight.jar
      [jar] Building jar: /home/ubuntu/floodlight/target/floodlight-test.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 29 seconds
```

Even building success, but how could i get rid of this info please?

Comment: Show us the build.xml or at the least the part with the `taskdef`.